# Problem with keyboard and trackpad on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

Have a really strange issue with my keyboard and trackpad after installing ubuntu 12.04. It picked up both fine with the livecd and in the install, but for quite awhile now, I find when I power my laptop up (Toshiba Satellite L775D-S7132), when I hit the login screen much of the time I won't have any keyboard or touchpad.

I can plug in a usb mouse and then at least restart or shut the laptop down and then keep trying until it picks it up correctly, but it's really a pain to have to do that all the time.

Are there quite a few bugs related to keyboard and trackpad issues with the new version?

I really want to get this issue resolved as it's a major nuisance.

Otherwise, my hardware gets picked up fine. Video, audio, wlan, usb work perfectly and I don't ever have any issues with them.

What's the best way to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a solution to this problem which has suddenly arisen on upgrading to 12.04 on an Inspiron N5110. With 11.10 there was no problem, the trackpad worked without any further configuration.

With 12.04 the trackpad works on the login screen but not after login on Unity 2D or 3D.

The solution on this computer turned out to be a key combination Fn F3 that turned the trackpad on and off.

The key combination differs for different models. See http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?docid=424135